# How should i go about baking textures for my model

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, baking

I continued learning blender after quite a while and cant seem to bake textures on 2.8 how i used to on previous versions. I have a simple model of a can of cola. need to bake the texture then edit and add the logo using photoshop. i have added the texture node to each material (i have two materials one red and the other silver) but when i do bake it gives me complete black output. Theres no red or silver anywhere to be seen. could someone guide me as to what i can do to get that color in my texture?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Are you trying to bake the difuse?

Comment: thank you, im trying to get the combined map, but even simple diffuse returns it completely black.

Comment: Did you have some light? Create a texture and not link to any ohter node. Keep it selected and mark Combined in Bake. Maybe it works now.

Comment: Yes, I have 4 light emitting surfaces set up , 3 at 33 degree angles to each other in the back and one illuminating the top.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I changed all materials and reassigned the textures and it worked.